# Error in paypal express checkout integration

Tags: java, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate Paypal in my website. But when i try to invoke the `setExpressCheckout` from the paypal api the program throws no such method error exception.

```
setExpressCheckoutResponse = service.setExpressCheckout(setExpressCheckoutReq);
```

stack Trace

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(Lurn/‌
 ​ebay/api/PayPalAPI/SetExpressCheckoutReq;)Lurn/ebay/api/PayPalAPI/SetExpressCheck‌
 ​outResponseType;
 controller.SetExpressCheckout.setExpressCheck(SetExpressCheckout.java:111)
 controller.SetExpressCheckout.execute(SetExpressCheckout.java:52)
```

Comment: use this codes for your reference:https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/merchant/SetExpressCheckout.java

Comment: You need more information here, such as what is the full stack trace of the exception, What is the class of Service, what version of the Paypal API jar are you using, are you sure you pulled it into your project correctly, what else have you done to try and troubleshoot?

Comment: i am using version 106 and i taken the code from https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/merchant/SetExpressCheckout.java

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(Lurn/ebay/api/PayPalAPI/SetExpressCheckoutReq;)Lurn/ebay/api/PayPalAPI/SetExpressCheckoutResponseType;

    controller.SetExpressCheckout.setExpressCheck(SetExpressCheckout.java:111)
    controller.SetExpressCheckout.execute(SetExpressCheckout.java:52)